# Convert code from Objective-C to Swift: ADBannerView

Tags: objective-c, swift, code-translation

I am trying to manually convert some code from Objective-C to Swift, but I only know how to use Swift.

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

I was able to convert the line starting with `ADBannerView *adView =` except for everything inside the `CGRectMake()`. I did not understand the second line starting with `[self.view`.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: That second line adds `adView` onto the `view` of your current object (`self`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correct understand what you need it will looks like:

```
var adView: ADBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50))
self.view.addSubview(adView)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let adView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 50, width: 320, height: 50))
self.view.addSubview(adView)
```